# by default select using php function

Tags: php, mysql

```
< select name="rtype" class="span6" >

< option >Select Residential Type< /option>

< option value="MultiStory Apartment" < ?php if($rtype="MultiStory Apartment"){ echo "selected";}? > > MultiStory Apartment< /option>

< option value="Residential Plot" < ?php if($rtype="Residential Plot"){ echo "selected";}? > >Residential Plot< /option>

< option value="Residential House" < ?php if($rtype="Residential House"){ echo "selected";} ?> >Residential House< /option>

< option value="DDA Flats" < ?php if($rtype="DDA Flats"){ echo "selected";} ?> >DDA Flats< /option>

< /select>
```

Comment: Comparison `==`, not `=`. Should be - `if($rtype == "MultiStory Apartment")`

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: There is not question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code as follows (comparison operation should be `$rtype==`)

```
    < select name="rtype" class="span6" > 
    < option >Select Residential Type< /option>
    < option value="MultiStory Apartment" < ?php if($rtype=="MultiStory Apartment"){ echo "selected";}? > > MultiStory Apartment< /option>
    < option value="Residential Plot" < ?php if($rtype=="Residential Plot"){ echo "selected";}? > >Residential Plot< /option>
    < option value="Residential House" < ?php if($rtype=="Residential House"){ echo "selected";} ?> >Residential House< /option>
    < option value="DDA Flats" < ?php if($rtype=="DDA Flats"){ echo "selected";} ?> >DDA Flats< /option>
< /select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you have made it too complex.

Also, change your comparison operator from `=` to `==`.

> a = $b     Assign      Sets $a to be equal to $b.
>
> $a == $b    Equal TRUE if $a is equal to $b.
>
> $a === $b   Identical   TRUE if $a is equal to $b, and they are of the same type. (introduced in PHP 4)

You can take an array and loop through it like this:

```
<?php
$rtypes = arrray();
$rtypes['MultiStory Apartment'] = 'MultiStory Apartment';
$rtypes['Residential Plot'] = 'Residential Plot';
$rtypes['Residential House'] = 'Residential House';
$rtypes['DDA Flats'] = 'DDA Flats';
?>
<select name="rtype" class="span6" >
<option >Select Residential Type< /option>
<?php
foreach ($rtypes as $option) {
  $selected = ($option == $rtype) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
  ?>  
  <option value="<?php echo $option;?>" <?php echo $selected;?>><?php echo $option;?></option>
  <?php
}
?>
</select>
```